# Android string resources not working with $

Tags: android, localization, aapt

After upgrading to android studio 3.0.1 the string resources with $ in their name
like: `<string name="$KEY$">value</string>`

throw an error

```
Error:(615, 3) error: resource 'string/$KEY$' has invalid entry name '$KEY$'. Invalid character '$KEY$'.
```

trace is:

> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"error: resource
>   \u0027string/$KEY$\u0027 has invalid entry name \u0027$KEY$\u0027.
>   Invalid character
>   \u0027$KEY$\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"../src/main/res/values-es/strings.xml","position":{"startLine":559,"startColumn":2,"startOffset":60748,"endColumn":54,"endOffset":60800}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

Answer (score 0):

Aapt2 is enabled by default when you use android plugin for gradle 3.0.
You can fix your issue by setting `android.enableAapt2=false` in your `gradle.properties`

Comment: '$' is an illegal character for a resource name. AAPT1 will be deprecated soon so instead I'd suggest refactoring the code to not include illegal characters.